# Retrieving data from a ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***My JS Ctrl:***

```
menuModule.controller('MenuPropertiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$location', 'ApplicationService', function ($scope, $modal, $location, ApplicationService) {

    var modal;
    $scope.propertieRef = '';

$scope.find_applications_by_name_for_diff = function (name) {
    console.log($scope.propertieRef);
    return ApplicationService.with_name_like(name).then(function (applicationsByName) {
        return _(applicationsByName).flatten().map(function (application) {
            application.title = application.name + ", " + application.version //Display purposes

            if((application.title === $scope.propertieRef))
            {
                application.title ='';
            }
            return application;
        }).value();
    });
};
....
}]);
```

***My HTML:***

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="propertiesRefApplication">Version de référence</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-trim="true" ng-model="propertieRef"
               id="propertiesRefApplication" placeholder="Propertie de référence"
               typeahead="application as application.title for application in find_applications_by_name_for_diff($viewValue)"/>
</div>
```

Why when i modify my input i don't retrieve  `$scope.propertieRef`

Comment: what print   console.log($scope.propertieRef); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you've linked to angular and wrapped your HTML with ngApp and ngController directives:

I've created a cut down version of your app here: http://jsfiddle.net/z0um7ht3/

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="MenuPropertiesCtrl">
    <label for="propertiesRefApplication">Version de référence</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required  ng-model="propertieRef"/>
    <span>{{propertieRef}}</span>
</div>
```

The ngApp directive is set on the body:

```
<body ng-app="menuModule">
```

(See the fiddle options)

Angular Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

NB: If you haven't gone through the phone cat tutorial, its worth a skim - https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I can't see all your code, but make sure that you:

1.Included script

```
 <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
```

2. Declare a dependency on ui.bootstrap

   `var menuModule =  angular.module('menuModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Please see here working demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/9r7YPZOoUV5cY1b0rb22?p=preview